# How to write responsive css for flex direction

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

I am trying to write responsive css for flex. I have used flex-direction row and column for responsive. But it is not working. So, How to show this div box as flexible for mobile and tab devices.

> For mobile: Div boxes should be like one below one(vertical).
> For Tab:
> Div boxes should be like(horizontal) over boxes it should be like next
> line.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-box-example-e2fqif?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px; 
}  

/* For Tablet View */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

/* For Mobile Portrait View */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* For Mobile Landscape View */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

/* For Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape View */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child magenta">Flex Column 1</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 2</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 3</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 4</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 5</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, instead of switching `flex-direction` from `row` to `column` using media queries, a more elegant way is to apply `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.flex-container` class, and then for each `.flex-child` apply `flex: 0 0 1` to facilitate natural wrapping.

After that, to control how many items you want in a row, you can use the `width` property within the `.flex-child` class. This method allows for precise adjustment of the layout, accommodating different screen sizes.

At the end your code will look like this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 0 0 1;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .flex-child {
    width: calc(100% / 6);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child magenta">Flex Column 1</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 2</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 3</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 4</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 5</div>
  <div class="flex-child green">Flex Column 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @sarann did you maybe try it out? Does it work for your case?

Comment: Min-width 768px is for tab. how to write css for mobile view?

Comment: Well this is a mobile-first approach so the default styles are specified for mobile screens, then you can just override styles for larger screens with media queries